# Need to create a CSV per day for output from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to create a CSV file from a stored procedure that runs everyday on SQL Server with shipping details.

What would be the best way to go about this?

The solution we found best was to call the stored procedure using Powershell and have a task running in windows scheduler everyday which runs the Powershell.

Comment: I am confused by the reference to oracle.

Comment: The live database is an oracle database which we only have read access to.  I tried to get it to work in SSIS but it seems to be missing the Oracle Home variable..couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Oracle but for SQL Server the easiest method I found was to use PowerShell.

```
$hostname = hostname
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $hostname -Database master -Query "select * from sys.sysdatabases" | Export-Csv "d:\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

gives a CSV file at desired location.

If your SQL Server is at remote location, please make sure your server can connect to said SQL Server and if any certificate/encryption is in place then you have all that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks DataStudent - this resolved our issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is BCP, or bulk command protocol. You essentially can either build this into the stored proc, or exclusively in the sql server agent job that runs it, or in an SSIS package. Wherever you prefer.

Here’s a link to Microsoft’s BCP utility:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

It is important to note you may need to enable some more advanced options in SQL Server. It is highly configurable though, including the ability to dump entire tables to a csv file.

Comment: It is also much much faster than other options.

Comment: Exactly this. If you’ve got a large amount of data, it’s really efficient.